# Setting python3 PYTHONHOME

Tags: python-3.x, docker, pip, root, site-packages

I installed python3 and pip3 using:

```
RUN apt install -y build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python3-dev
RUN apt install -y python3-pip
```

For some reason site-packages are showing up like this:

```
root@5d6f29f1d4e9:/usr/local/lib/python2.7# ls -a
.  ..  dist-packages  site-packages
root@5d6f29f1d4e9:/usr/local/lib/python3.6# ls -a
.  ..  dist-packages
```

My only guess is that I should set PYTHONHOME to point to 3.x instead of 2.x? e.g.:

```
ENV PYTHONHOME /usr/local/lib/python3.6
```

(note I am root user in a docker container so just need one python version and I won't need virtualenv / venv).

Comment: You shouldn't need to set that variable at all; running `pip3` will install things into the system-default tree, which is right in Docker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nah I don't think this was it. I did this:

```
RUN apt install -y build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python3-dev
RUN apt install -y python3-pip

ENV PYTHONHOME /usr/local/lib/python3.6

RUN pip3 install awscli
```

and it then failed with some unnecessary error when installing awscli, so setting this env var doesn't seem like the right thing to do.